# Turn off (Ignore) placeholder attribute in html text/search elements

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs

I would like to be able to turn on/off the placeholder from my search boxes if possible.

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
 <input type="search" placeholder="Type to search" />
```

What I have tried so far:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{
   content: "";
   color:red; /*test selector*/
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cqocxhzt/1/

Comment: @epascarello can you give me a -*little bit more*- straight answer? I'm not getting it

Comment: try `color: transparent` if you want do it with css to "hide" the placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this with angular is:

In the controller:

```
$scope.placeholder_value1 = ""; //empty
$scope.placeholder_value2 = "some value"; //some value
```

In the view:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder_value1}}" />
<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder_value2}}" />
```

Comment: This is -*in fact*- an answer that I will consider for next design, but not a solution to the laziness of manually removing the placeholders now (and potentially, adding them back again in short time). Thanks!